# Ignore a specific builtin "id" using Pylint - Python

Tags: python, pylint

I would like to allow to redefine id as an attribute in a generic class.
Pylint catches this error as:
`bam_sdk\core_element.py:7:44: W0622: Redefining built-in 'id' (redefined-builtin)`
I would like to allow "id" to be overwritten, however not other builtin's like "int, str etc.".

Is there a way to only disable this specific error for only this specific value "id"?

```
from typing import Optional


class Element:
    counter = 1

    def __init__(self, name: Optional[str], id: Optional[int]) -> None:
        self.id = id if id else self.__class__.counter
        self.name = name if name else f"{self.__class__.__name__}-{self.id}"
        self.__class__.counter += 1
```

Comment: I don't know why you are fretting about what `pylint` has to say. It has heuristics intended to detect code smells (laudable), but some of its *dicta* are nonsense. That you want to suppress the message for *one* instance of a complaint but not for other instances of the same complaint illustrates that you share that view. Just disable the message entirely, or ignore it. When writing in English (but not French or Dutch) I switch the spell checker off because I reckon I can spell better. But I will switch it on for *one* pass over an important document to catch doubled words and genuine typos.

Comment: @BoarGules It's perfectly reasonable to want to clear *all* warnings, so that real problems later don't get swallowed up in the noise.

Comment: In this case, eliminating the problem is less obstructive than adding a comment like `# noqa W0622` (or whatever syntax Pylint uses).

Comment: @chepner Agreed. But I'm not sure that all `pylint` heuristics have the status of compiler warnings.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. What Pylint reports may or may not also be mentioned by the compiler. (It may ignore things the compiler reports, and it definitely reports things the compiler ignores--that's the point of a linter.) What's important is that just like compiler warnings, you want to deal with the issue in *some* way, so that you don't condition yourself to ignore Pylint's output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the attribute it's complaining about; it's the parameter  name. The standard convention is to append a `_` to the name to avoid the shadowing.

```
def __init__(self, name: Optional[str], id_: Optional[int]) -> None:
    self.id = id_ if id_ else self.__class__.counter
    self.name = name if name else f"{self.__class__.__name__}-{self.id}"
    self.__class__.counter += 1
```

I find it slightly cleaner to modify the value of the parameter rather than using a conditional expression.

```
def __init__(self, name: Optional[str], id_: Optional[int]) -> None:
    if id_ is None:
        id_ = self.__class__.counter

    if name is None:
        name = f"{self.__class__.__name__}-{id_}"

    self.id = id_
    self.name = name
    self.__class__.counter += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the remark and readability suggestion!

Comment: In the second version, there's a typo in `if name_ is None:`. Should be `name` with no trailing underscore.

Comment: Thanks; not sure why I made that typo. (Then again, if I knew, it wouldn't be a typo, but some other error :) )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually do what the question asked and just configure pylint to not complain about certain builtins being redefined, that's easy enough to do:

```
# pyproject.toml
[tool.pylint."messages control"]
allowed-redefined-builtins = [ 'id' ]
```